# Treeview in ContextMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, contextmenu

I got this crazy idea trying to display a tree in a context menu. I did a google search and cudnt find anything related. Can this actually be achieved? I know I am not posting in any code, but wanted to get all your guidelines before I start with the coding part of it.

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: Do you have a mockup image you could share?

Comment: I am sorry Richard. I do not have such an image presently which I can share. Will surely keep you informed if I get through this.. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one work around comes in my mind here. You should first of all disable the default conextmenu. And then you can show your absolutely positioned div which contains a treeview next to the cursor.